# AX88179 Ethernet Adapter drops connection after idling

Tags: network, usb, monterey, ethernet

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro (Touchbar) running macOS Monterey 12.5

I've connected a StarTech USB-C dongle that comes with USB-A ports and a Ethernet port to this MacBook. The Ethernet controller on the dongle is a ASIX AX88179 for which I have installed the drivers and as long as I connect it to a specific USB port on the MacBook, the Ethernet connection is recognized and works correctly.

However, I'm having this strange problem where if I'm using the MacBook for a while and then let it idle, the Ethernet connection gets disabled. Once I start using the MacBook again, after 30 seconds or so the Ethernet connection seems to "wake up" and starts working again.

Things I have tried without any success:

- Create a new location in System Preferences>Network and ensure the Ethernet adapter is the first entry.
- Ensure that in System Preferences>Battery>Power Adapter, the option to "wake for network access" is checked and the option to "Prevent your Mac from sleeping automatically when the display is off" is also checked.

Any suggestions on how I can debug this issue further or any known solutions would be very welcome!

Comment: I suspect your MacBook Pro either sleeps when idle or turns off the dongle to save power. Does running a `ping` (for example to your router) in the background help? Just wondering: I'm on Monterey 12.5 (MacBook Pro 2020 13") and I don't see the option "Prevent Mac from sleeping when lid is closed" but "Prevent your Mac from sleeping automatically when the display is off", do you see the former or the latter?

Comment: >  Does running a ping (for example to your router) in the background help? 


This does not seem to help unfortunately. I ran the command `ping -S eth.ip.add.ress -i 30 rou.ter.ip.add` which pings the router every 30 seconds and after some time I could not VNC to the machine. Interestingly, the pings never failed it's just that the machine was not responding to VNC requests.


> do you see the former or the latter?


The latter. My apologies. I mis-remembered the name of the setting when submitting the question.